# Why is it necessary to take a new variable "head" in for loop?

Tags: python, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.ref = None

def Print_LL(linkedlist):
    if linkedlist is None:
        print("LinkedList is empty!!")
    else:
        while linkedlist is not None:
            print(linkedlist.data)
            linkedlist = linkedlist.ref

def arr_to_LL(arr, n):
    linkedlist = None

    for i in range(0,n):
        new_node = Node(arr[i])

        if linkedlist is None:
            linkedlist = new_node
        else:
            head = linkedlist
            while head.ref is not None:
                head = head.ref
            head.ref = new_node
    return linkedlist
```

*why to take "head" variable? why cant we continue with linkedlist*

Comment: Removed `dsa` tag: is not about Digital Signature Algorithm.

Comment: Draw a diagram for a couple of cases and you will find the answer yourself. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#/media/File:Singly-linked-list.svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`linkedlist` is a reference to the head of the list. `head`, despite the name, is just a reference to the *end* of the list, or more specifically to the node to which you'll attach a new node. A better definition of `arr_to_LL` might be

```
def arr_to_LL(arr):
    head = None

    for v in arr:
        new_node = Node(v)

        if head is None:
            head = new_node
        else:
            curr.ref = new_node

        curr = new_node
           
    return head
```

This `for` loop has two invariants:

1. `head` always refers to the front of the (possibly empty) linked list.
2. `curr` (once defined) always refers to the *end* of the linked list.

As you iterate over the array, you simply append a new node to the end, then update the end.

If you use the common convention of an empty linked list represented by a dummy node, it becomes even simpler, as now you don't need a special case for `head is None`.

```
def arr_to_LL(arr):
    # We'll store the length in the dummy node, because why not?
    head = curr = Node(0)

    for v in arr:
        curr.ref = Node(v)
        curr = new_node
        head.data += 1
           
    return head
```

Comment: Yeah, `head` is a really bad name in the code in the question. Plus, the code in the question searches for the tail of the list all over again on each iteration of the `for` loop, making it take quadratic time.